# Laravel: Tricky redirection after login

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect

My app first does a request into a web service to get the user from an ERP.
If the users exist on ERP database, I do register him into my database so I can access later.
Because of the WS routine my code looks like:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $this->credentials($request);
        $login = $credentials[$this->username()];
        $cpfCnpjHigienizado = str_replace('-', '', str_replace('/', '', (str_replace('.', '', $request->cpfCnpj))));
        $credenciais = User::where('cpfCnpj', '=', $cpfCnpjHigienizado)->first();
        if ($credenciais) { // Se já estiver cadastro, vai pra home
            return redirect(route('home'));
        } else {
        // do the Soap connection
}
```

Ok, so if the user is registered on my DB, goes to homepage and doesn't need to do the heavy Soap connection again.

This is working fine.
Now the project need to send an email to a pre-registered user like:

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => env('APP_URL') .'/SobeDocsFiadorCadastrado/'. $fiador->id ])
Clique para iniciar
@endcomponent
```

Now, this user should login first, then goes to the email's URL. But, he goes to the homepage instead.
How can I make this works? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This's how to redirect to another route by name of the route and passing email as parameter:

```
return redirect()->route('new_route_name', ['email' => 'set email here']);
```

Check this for more info:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects